# NPM fs module not included in Laravel 5.4 with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, npm

I just realized Laravel 5.4 does not include the fs module when I needed it.

I need that module for reading files. And https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs seems to be deprecated?

Is there any way to install this module?

Answer (score 1):

The fs module is part of Node.js itself. You don't install it, you just use it.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html